# Recover data from exFAT formatted HDD

Tags: data-recovery, fat32, exfat

I have a WD Elements 1TB HDD (originally with FAT32 system) which was mistakenly formatted (quickformat option) to exFAT file system using windows 7 format command. I primarily have personal photos, music and movies on the HDD. How do I recover my lost data now? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You've erased the file table of the HD partition. In this case you will need a blind recover software, which will read every content and try to discovery the file based in it's header.

Here are some recommendations: http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools